# What is the difference between `PropTypes.node` and `PropTypes.any` in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
// Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array
// (or fragment) containing these types.
optionalNode: PropTypes.node,

// A value of any data type
requiredAny: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
```

Which types does `PropTypes.any` contain compared to `PropTypes.node`?

Comment: The difference is specified in the comments.

Answer (score 39):

**PropTypes** are a way to validate the values that are passed in through our props.

**node**
We can pass anything that can be rendered, such as numbers, string, DOM elements, arrays, or fragments that contain them using the React.PropTypes.node.

**any type**
React allows us to specify that a prop must be present, regardless of it's type. We can do this by using the React.PropTypes.any validator.

Comment: you didn't specify any type that would pass `PropTypes.any` and fail `PropTypes.node`. I don't think this answer is complete.

Comment: Yes, here props accept as `HTML` node element in a `DOM`.

Comment: Your description of `any` sounds more like the description of the `isRequired` modifier. `any` means it can hold *any* type of value, but the prop remains optional. In fact, it cannot be a required a prop, because defining `any` defeats that purpose, unless `undefined` is excluded from `any`.

Answer (score 28):

`PropTypes.node:` any render-able value like numbers and string, that can actually be rendered on screen.

`PropTypes.any:` any type of value, even those are non-render-able like boolean.

Incase of `<div>{true}</div>` JSX code,

`booleanValue: PropTypes.node` will give an error, while
`booleanValue: PropTypes.any` will not give any such error.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't JSX be `PropTypes.node` as it's render-able

Comment: sorry for being a necromancer but how is `<div>{true}</div>` not a node? could you elaborate on that? did you mean to say `<div>{booleanValue}</div>` ? But even that why would that fail?

Comment: @RichardBarker if I understand correctly, true/false cant be rendered (hence "not renderable node") on screen. Try rendering `<div>{ture}</div>`, it will render nothing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NitinJadhav just because you don't see it it doesn't mean not rendered.